# Auto type in Powershell

Tags: autorun

I wanted my computer to auto-type every x number of seconds. I have this script but I can't get this to work:

```
param($minutes = 180)

$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $minutes; $i++) {
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
  $myshell.sendkeys(".")
}
```

I'm getting this warning when I paste it.
[image: Warning]

Please advise, TIA

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not use images to post code or error message unless the image is conveying something more than the code or error message. If you need to you should augment the image with the text it contains because images of text are not searchable, accessible, and they make it harder for people trying to help you. Please read [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Click "Paste anyway" to run the commands. It's just warning you that the commands are going to run immediately.

Comment: The message warns that the clipboard contains not one but multiple lines which might behave unexpectedly. After clicking "Paste anyway" the poster needs to verify the correct execution of the code.